# How to skip NULL (or 0) when using Row_Number?

Tags: sql

I need to return the sequential number of a row based on values in `ColValue`. I need to do it until NULL occurs in a row, then start to count from the beginning. My original table is in the left picture, what I need is on the right (column `RowNr`):

[image: This is what I have now:]    [[image: This is what I need:2]

I tried various combinations of `ROW_NUMBER` but in vain. Instead of NULL I can also set 0 or other value but the issue is how to start counting from the beginning right after this value.

One of my tries is here:

```
    SELECT journalized_id, ColValue,
        CASE WHEN ColValue IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE WHEN ColValue IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY ColValue) END AS RowNr
    FROM TableX
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: . . Your results do not match your query, because the results are not ordered by `colvalue`.

Comment: My result must be exactly as showed in pic on the right. Don't know if I get you right but when I use `order by` on result dataset then all NULLs will be on the top and rest of values in order.

Comment: . . You need a column to specify the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mustafa00, I believe @GordonLinoff's answer is essentially correct. The main issue is that he has the `colvalue` field performing two roles which are incompatible. An understandable problem given how the question was presented. You need to find another field (or set of fields), to play one of those roles. Without that the question cannot be answered.

```
SELECT
    SubQuery.SomeOtherField,
    SubQuery.Journalized_Id,
    SubQuery.ColValue,
    SubQuery.Grp, --So you can see what it outputs
    CASE
        WHEN SubQuery.ColValue IS NOT NULL
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SubQuery.Grp ORDER BY SubQuery.SomeOtherField)
    END - (CASE WHEN SubQuery.Grp = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS RowNr 
          --A minor correction to Gordon's code to ensure each sequence starts at 1.
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        t.SomeOtherField,
        t.Journalized_Id,
        t.ColValue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.ColValue IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            OVER (ORDER BY t.SomeOtherField) AS Grp
    FROM
        MyTable t
    ) SubQuery
```

The `SubQuery` is creating groups for each set of records requiring it's own number sequence starting at 1. It does this by counting the number of `NULL` values in `ColValue` which come *before* the current record. It can't do this unless we can give the query some means of understanding which records are really *before* the others, and to do that you need `SomeOtherField` (or set of fields) by which to order the records.

It is likely that there is some primary key to your table that can play the role of `SomeOtherField`.

This solution is demonstrated with your data plus `SomeOtherField` in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e66b/6/0).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I really wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to count the number of `NULL` values *after* a given row.  That assigns the non `NULL` values a grouping.  Then use `row_number()`:

```
select x.*,
       (case when colvalue is not null
             then row_number() over (partition by grp order by colvalue)
        end) as seqnum
from (select x.*,
             sum(case when colvalue is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by colvalue) as grp 
      from tablex x
     ) x
```

Comment: I don't think this can be quite right. `colvalue` can't be both the thing to order by and the thing to reset the count to zero. I think more info is needed from the OP to say how the records are ordered.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Records must be ordered as in the picture and what I mean by this is that the order can not be changed.

Comment: @mustafa00 . . . The ordering in **your** query is by `colvalue`.  You should use the same ordering here.

Comment: @mustafa00, rows in a database don't have an intrinsic order, is there an `order by` clause you are applying to your query to get the data to come out as in your question?

Comment: @SteveLovell I don't use `order by` to my original query. I added this chunk of code to my question to show one of my tries to solve the problem but it doesn't work. @GordonLinoff, yes I used such an ordering but it's not working properly that's why I asked question here on SO.

Comment: I think such an `order by` is a prerequisite for this question being answerable at all. Is there one that you _could_ apply? It may be related to the primary key of your table.